# Xcode and the iPad simulator

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-simulator

I have just installed Apple's SDK 3.2. When I run the iPad simulator Safari doesnt appear in it. Can anyone help?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Am I wrong, or isn't the beta still under NDA? If it is, it can't be discussed here. Alas.

Answer (score 2):

On the iPhone simulator, at least, homegrown apps usually get installed on the second page of the home screen, which makes it look like none of the built-in apps are there. Try swiping back to the first page of the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have Beta 1? I think they are upto Beta 3 now. Also you should ask iPad related questions on Apple's Beta Dev forum since its under NDA.